# way of knowing which facebook pages the User is administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to know which pages (ids) the user is logged in administrator to read the information to them but not acehi refenrecia in openGraphApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the user with the `manage_pages` permission. After that, just call `/me/accounts` and you will get all Pages where the user is admin (or got some other role).